# Swipe view from different layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, gesture, viewflipper

I have a screen split in 2. The bottom half is white and the top half is green. I want to use the swipe gesture only on the white zone so that when I swipe left or right the green zone changes colors. I want only the white zone to recognize gestures, the green one just changes colors when O swipe on the white zone.

Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

Answer (score 0):

On your white view, register a touch listener to detect the gestures you need.

Look this:
[Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)